# Snapshot.data not showing data occasionally

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a FutureBuilder widget and when Flutter communicates with Firebase, it doesn't show the data. But, whenever I remove two fields I recently added out of the 6, it works and show the data. The fields to be removed are incomeTotal and expenseTotal

## Code

**Read data function**

```
Stream<List<CardDetails>> readCards() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('cards')
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((doc) => CardDetails.fromJson(doc.data()))
          .toList());
```

**Load data onto widget**

```
StreamBuilder<List<CardDetails>>(
    stream: readCards(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Text("error");
      } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
          snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color:
                  const Color.fromARGB(50, 0, 0, 0),
              borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          child: Transform.scale(
              scale: 1.5,
              child: Lottie.asset(
                  "lib/images/space_animation.json")),
        );
      } else {
        final cards = snapshot.data!;
        if (cardIdOfficial == '') {
          WidgetsBinding.instance
              .addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            setState(() {
              cardIdOfficial = snapshot
                  .data![_pageViewController
                      .initialPage]
                  .id;
            });
          });
        }
    
        return PageView(
            padEnds: false,
            controller: _pageViewController,
            onPageChanged: (value) => {
                  setState(() {
                    cardIdOfficial =
                        snapshot.data![value].id;
                  })
                },
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            children:
                cards.map(buildCards).toList());
      }
    }),
```

**Model**

```
class CardDetails {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final double balance;
  final int cardDigits;
  final int incomeTotal;
  final int expenseTotal;

  CardDetails({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.balance,
    required this.cardDigits,
    required this.incomeTotal,
    required this.expenseTotal,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'title': title,
        'balance': balance,
        'cardDigits': cardDigits,
        'incomeTotal': incomeTotal,
        'expenseTotal': expenseTotal,
      };
  static CardDetails fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CardDetails(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      balance: json['balance'],
      cardDigits: json['cardDigits'],
      incomeTotal: json['incomeTotal'],
      expenseTotal: json['expenseTotal']);
}
```

Everything was fine until I added those two fields, when I remove them everything looks fine. What I also did was change the variable name to just income instead of incomeTotal and ran it again, it worked but then this happened again twice.

```
Flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 11.6.3 20G415 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Flutter dependencies

```
dependencies:
- cloud_firestore 4.3.1 [cloud_firestore_platform_interface cloud_firestore_web collection firebase_core firebase_core_platform_interface flutter meta]
- cupertino_icons 1.0.5
- custom_refresh_indicator 2.0.1 [flutter]
- firebase_core 2.4.1 [firebase_core_platform_interface firebase_core_web flutter meta]
- fluentui_icons 1.0.0 [flutter]
- fluentui_system_icons 1.1.190 [flutter]
- flutter 0.0.0 [characters collection js material_color_utilities meta vector_math sky_engine]
- flutter_slidable 2.0.0 [flutter]
- gap 2.0.1 [flutter]
- google_fonts 3.0.1 [flutter http path_provider crypto]
- google_nav_bar 5.0.6 [flutter]
- grouped_list 5.1.2 [flutter]
- intl 0.18.0 [clock meta path]
- lottie 2.2.0 [archive flutter path vector_math]
- metaballs 1.4.2 [flutter]
- provider 6.0.5 [collection flutter nested]
- sizer 2.0.15 [universal_io flutter]
- smooth_page_indicator 1.0.0+2 [flutter]
```

**What happens**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmaks.png)

**What happens when I remove the two fields, what needs to happen** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcPCY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, as far as I can tell. One possible issue I can think of:

Are you *sure* that every document within the `cards` collection in your Firestore database has those fields present and are integer values?

If one of those values wasn’t present on a document (or was of the wrong type), your deserialization (`fromJson`) would blow up.

In the past I’ve had trouble with this because it’s not always obvious that an error is being thrown - it’s sometimes swallowed within the internals of the stream.

Comment: Thank you, but no even when the collection is empty it would still give that problem. I also have a widget if there is empty data but that doesn't even display when those two fields are there, but when they are both removed everything works fine.